# Is it possible to make a connection between 2 PCs using cable modems (DOCSIS, RG6)?

Tags: networking, modem, cable-modem

I'm experimenting with communication technologies and try to setup a PC to PC connection using different types of hardware, medium, protocols, etc. (i.e. direct connection using Null-modem cables and RS-232, using modem connection via phone line, etc.) but I was stuck during my attempt to perform the same task using a so called Cable modem (that uses coax RG6 as a medium). I'm aware that usual operations using cable modem is the following:

**(1)** PC |---> Ethernet cable |--->  Cable modem (i.e. Arris) |---> RG6 |---> CMTS (Cable Modem Termination System) |---> Cable provider's IP network

On the other hand the following schema was widely used in the past:

**(2)** PC |---> RS-232 cable |--->  Dial-up modem |---> phone line |---> PSTN (Public Switched Telephone Network) |---> dial-up modem |---> RS-232 cable |---> PC

The above (2) could be modified at the local level at:

**(3)** PC |---> RS-232 cable |--->  Dial-up modem |---> Private PBX (i.e. from Panasonic, Samsung, etc.) |---> dial-up modem |---> RS-232 cable - PC

So the question is: is it possible to implement a schema **(3)** for a pair of cable modems at the local level (even, if it should be modified/tweaked).

Comment: This was in wide use in the industry. Before VPN and IP tunelling became common, companies were using their private lines to connect two offices. But whether it's possible with a random set of cable modems or whether you need a particular type I don't know.

Comment: @PMF: True, but those weren't DOCSIS-based connections – a direct point-to-point link would've used something simpler and symmetric like HDLC, I think... and many "private lines" were things like Frame Relay VPNs.

Comment: For fun, you might include dial-up modems. Using 1200 bps modems and a 24-volt power supply to simulate POTS connectivity (yes, it should have been 48 VDC, but 24 VDC with a 600 ohm resistor worked), I got Atari 600 XL and 800 XL computers communicating in the 1980's. Pioneer data rate was 2400 down to 16 bps https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=1972-012A

Comment: @PMF, actually, I'm able to grab two modems produced by the same company. Moreover, it's highly likely that I even could grab exactly the same part numbers. BUT the point it that I don't understand internals - does modem produce some electric carrier to the line (if yes, what exactly) or it is only a CMTS role to provide some power line, etc.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, actually, It's absolutely no problem to do this for me even now, due to the only thing I need is local hardware PBX that can be bought freely and is very affordable. The main reason for the question was to find out the way to establish a connection without using PBX hardware (RG9 but not 10BaseT in that case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no – DOCSIS is a deliberately asymmetric protocol, with different frequency bands and modulations used in the 'upstream' and 'downstream' directions. The protocol already expects that multiple cable modems will be connected to the same coax cable, but all of them will be talking only to the CMTS (even traffic between two CMs has to go through the CMTS<sup>1</sup>), *and* the CMTS will be providing a clock signal for the modems to share the upstream-to-CMTS channel (using TDMA).

You'll find all the details on physical and link layers in ITU-T specifications [J.222.1](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-J.222.1-200707-I/en) and [J.222.2](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-J.222.2-200707-I/en) which document DOCSIS 3.0, as well as [J.112](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-J.112-199803-I/en) for the older DOCSIS 1.1.

See for example [J.112](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-J.112-199803-I/en) (DOCSIS 1.1) section B.7 "Cable modem – CMTS interaction". Both cable modems will wait for specific messages from a CMTS before they proceed, including the assignment of "upstream" channels as well as timing information.

So even if the modems are physically capable of receiving on what would normally be their 'upstream' frequencies and vice versa, they still won't have the software that would perform the functions that the other modem expects.

<sup>1</sup> ([J.222.2](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-J.222.2-200707-I/en) (DOCSIS 3.0) section 9.1.1.2 even explicitly says that "hosts attached to different CMs can communicate only via the CMTS".)

If you're looking for protocols that use same medium, MoCA is probably the most common protocol for local networking over coax. Old 10 Mbps Ethernet (10BASE2, 10BROAD36) also used several types of coax – though most of it was different types from that used for TV – before switching to twisted-pair.